# Missing property name marshalling response to WCF web service

Tags: java, web-services, wcf

I have imported the following xsd definition (Netbeans 8.0.2) for calling a WCF generated web service.

```
<xs:complexType name="PagingInformation">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FirstRowIndex" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LastRowIndex" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SortDirection" type="tns:SortDirection"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SortFieldName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="PagingInformation" nillable="true" type="tns:PagingInformation"/>
<xs:simpleType name="SortDirection">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Ascending"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Descending"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

When I call the web service with the generated java class, then the marshalled response does not contain the name of the simple types FirstRowIndex and LastRowIndex:

```
  <ns4:pagingInformation>
    <ns8:int>1</ns8:int>
    <ns8:int>100</ns8:int>
    <ns2:SortDirection>Ascending</ns2:SortDirection>
  </ns4:pagingInformation>
  <ns4:detailLevel>Summary</ns4:detailLevel>
```

As a consequence I get an error back from the web service that I am missing the two parameters. The similar and successful call from a .net based client marshals the following

```
  <a:FirstRowIndex>1</a:FirstRowIndex>
  <a:LastRowIndex>100</a:LastRowIndex>
  <a:SortDirection>Ascending</a:SortDirection>
  <a:SortFieldName i:nil="true"></a:SortFieldName>
```

I need some input as how to ensure I call the web service correctly

Comment: Well, I figured it out myself: I had called the FirstRowIndex method with the objectFactory's createInt method instead of the specific PagingInformationFirstRowIndex method